# Свой маркер + картинка (Яндекс.Карты)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Задача — стилизовать маркер и вставлять в него контент (картинку).
Использую JavaScript API 2.1 Яндекс.Карт.

Зашёл в песочницу, откопал код, добавил картинку (иконку маркера), но `iconContent: "фото"` почему-то не отображается.

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

```
myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
    iconContent: "фото саши",
    hintContent: 'Cаша в школе'
}, {
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageHref: 'img/marker-green-photo.png',
    iconImageSize: [50, 62],
    iconImageOffset: [0, 0],
});

myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
```

Comment: попробуйте абсолютный путь до изображения, типа `http://example.com/img/marker-green-photo.png`

Comment: @xaja даже просто текст не выводится, такое ощущение, что одновременно подставлять свой стиль метки `iconImageHref: 'img/marker-green-photo.png'` и контента `iconContent: "...",` - нельзя, надеюсь это не так)

Comment: более внимательно прочитал ваш вопрос - думал, что картинка не выводится... одновременно использовать `iconImageHref` и `iconContent` действительно нельзя, но у яндекса есть вот такая штука - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape

Comment: @xaja, огромное спасибо, это то, что нужно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться созданием полностью своей HTML-метки: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape