# ссылка на локальный файл с иконкой маркера

Tags: javascript

Проблема похожая на [Свой маркер + картинка (Яндекс.Карты)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443643/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B), но я не использую `iconContent`

Так работает:

```
 marker = new window.ymaps.Placemark(
                    item.position,
                    {
                        balloonContent: title
                    },
                    {
                        iconLayout: 'default#image',
                        iconImageHref: 'http://webmap-blog.ru/files/gmap/gicon/mm_20_red.png',
                        iconImageSize: [20, 30],
                        iconImageOffset: [-10, -30],
                        draggable: true
                    }
                )
```

Если же задать путь до того-же файла, положенного в локальную папку:

```
iconImageHref: 'img/mm_20_red.png'
```

в этом случае маркер не хочет отображаться. Может кто подскажет

Comment: попробуйте так, используя полный путь к локальному файлу:  `file:\\path`

Comment: все-равно не хочет